# Adding src to the video source is not working when base64 is added to the src

Tags: java, jquery, video, base64

I am retrieving video from oracle database using java and sending response with base64 value here is my java code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {   String video64="";   
    System.out.println("service");
        try {   
            PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select * from video ");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            Blob vedio=rs.getBlob(1);    
        System.out.println("try");
            if(vedio !=null)   
            {
            byte videobytes[]=vedio.getBytes(1,(int)vedio.length());
            video64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(videobytes);
            } 
        } catch (SQLException e) {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(video64);  
        response.getWriter().write(video64);      
    }
 here is my html 
<video controls> 
  <source type="video/mp4"  id="v"> 
</video>
```

i am using ajax call to send request and adding my response to the `<source type="video/mp4"  id="v">` using jquery
here is ajax

```
$("#sub").click(function(){  
        $.ajax({
                url:"RetriveVedio",
                method: "get",
                dataType: 'text', 
                success:function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#v").attr("src",'data:video/mp4;base64,'+response);
                    $("#v").load();
                }   
        });     
    });
```

But `src` is not getting added to the source , and `base64` value also not working for `video tag` 
this is base64 value that i am getting as response `AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDFpc29tBNjldm1kYXQAAAAAAAAAEAA=`
what is the problem with this?

Answer (score 1):

everything with the above code is fine .But the `blob` was incorrect ,when i am inserting video using java into the `database` video is not properly converted into the `byteStream`.
That is why the response `AAAAGGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDFpc29tBNjldm1kYXQAAAAAAAAAEAA=`  was wrong .
that is why the above code did not work